# rsync not synchronizing .htaccess file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, wildcard, rsync

I am trying to rsync directory A of server1 with directory B of server2.

Sitting in the directory A of server1, I ran the following commands.

```
rsync -av * server2::sharename/B
```

but the interesting thing is, it synchronizes all files and directories except .htaccess or any hidden file in the directory A. Any hidden files within subdirectories get synchronized.

I also tried the following command:

```
rsync -av --include=".htaccess" * server2::sharename/B
```

but the results are the same.

Any ideas why hidden files of A directory are not getting synchronized and how to fix it. I am running as root user.

thanks

Comment: I've you're satisfied with one answer, you should accept it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 118):

This is due to the fact that `*` is by default expanded to all files in the current working directory except the files whose name starts with a dot. Thus, `rsync` never receives these files as arguments.

You can pass `.` denoting current working directory to `rsync`:

```
rsync -av . server2::sharename/B
```

This way `rsync` will look for files to transfer in the current working directory as opposed to looking for them in what `*` expands to.

Alternatively, you can use the following command to make `*` expand to all files including those which start with a dot:

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

See also [shopt manpage](http://ss64.com/bash/shopt.html).

Comment: Indeed '.' solves the issue, e.g. `rsync -avz user@domain.com:/remote/path/. /destination/path` does the job

Answer (score 61):

For anyone who's just trying to sync directories between servers (including all hidden files) -- e.g., syncing `somedirA` on `source-server` to `somedirB` on a destination server -- **try this**:

```
rsync -avz -e ssh --progress user@source-server:/somedirA/ somedirB/
```

**Note the slashes at the end of both paths.** Any other syntax may lead to unexpected results!

---

Also, for me its easiest to perform `rsync` commands from the destination server, because it's easier to make sure I've got proper write access (i.e., I might need to add `sudo` to the command above).

Probably goes without saying, but obviously your remote user also needs read access to `somedirA` on your source server. :)

Comment: Was it the -e flag that will sync the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @JesseBurcsik No, the `-e ssh` specifies the method for connecting.

Comment: You just need slash on the source, destination doesn't matter

Answer (score 34):

I had the same issue.

For me when I did the following command the hidden files did **not** get rsync'ed

```
rsync -av /home/user1 server02:/home/user1
```

But when I added the slashes at the end of the paths, the hidden files were rsync'ed.

```
rsync -av /home/user1/ server02:/home/user1/
```

**Note the slashes at the end of the paths**, as Brian Lacy said the slashes are the key.  I don't have the reputation to comment on his post or I would have done that.

Comment: Just add `shopt -s dotglob` to your script before the rsync

Comment: (Over the course of years I have made it an iron rule (on many scripts and occasions): trailing slash ALWAYS on source, NEVER on dest. I even enforce this in wrapping helper routines...)

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is due to shell wildcard expansion. Use . instead of star.

Consider the following example directory content

```
$ ls -a .
. .. .htaccess a.html z.js
```

The shell's wildcard expansion translates the argument list that the rsync program gets from

```
-av * server2::sharename/B
```

into

```
-av a.html z.js server2::sharename/B
```

before the command starts getting executed.

Answer (score 3):

The `*` tell to rsynch to not synch hidden files. You should not omit it.

Answer (score 0):

On a related note, in case any are coming in from google etc trying to find while `rsync` is not copying hidden subfolders, I found one additional reason why this can happen and figured I'd pay it forward for the next guy running into the same thing: if you are using the `-C` option (obviously the `--exclude` would do it too but I figure that one's a bit easier to spot).

In my case, I had a script that was copying several folders across computers, including a directory with several git projects and I noticed that the I couldn't run any of the normal `git` commands in the copied repos (yes, normally one should use `git clone` but this was part of a larger backup that included other things). After looking at the script, I found that it was calling `rsync` with 7 or 8 options.

After googling didn't turn up any obvious answers, I started going through the switches one by one. After dropping the `-C` option, it worked correctly. In the case of the script, the `-C` flag appears to have been added as a mistake, likely because `sftp` was originally used and `-C` is a compression-related option under that tool.

per `man rsync`, the option is described as

> --cvs-exclude, -C        auto-ignore files in the same way CVS does

Since CVS is an older version control system, and given the man page description, it makes perfect sense that it would behave this way.